# Redefine/alias a resource in WPF?

Tags: wpf, resources

Is there a way to redefine/alias an existing `SolidColorBrush` (or any other resource, actually)?

Case in point: I have a brush in an external ResourceDictionary that I want to reference by my own key instead of the original key. I don't want to be dependent on the external reference, since the actual brush is prone to change in the future.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Window.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="SomeExternalResource">Red</SolidColorBrush>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <StaticResourceExtension ResourceKey="SomeExternalResource" x:Key="SomeAliasedResource"/>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Border Background="{StaticResource SomeAliasedResource}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

> I don't want to be dependent on the
>   external reference, since the actual
>   brush is prone to change in the
>   future.

You'll still be dependent on the external resource, just not in as many places.

Comment: the only limitation to this is that you can't reference both the original and the alias if used within the same resource dictionary, as they will override each other. i am assuming this applies to multiple dictionaries you merge at application scope.

Comment: Judging by the way the question is worded, he doesn't want to reference the original - only his alias. Referencing the original would defeat the purpose of creating the alias.

Comment: This is NOT working for me.  I get <<An object of the type "System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension" cannot be applied to a property that expects the type "System.Windows.Media.Brush">>.

Answer (score 6):

I have an update to [Ruedi's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/470328/ruedi-steinmann) solution.  This works for resources both within the same resource dictionary and anywhere within the application.

```
public class Alias : MarkupExtension
{
    public string ResourceKey { get; set; }

    public Alias()
    {

    }
    public Alias(string resourceKey)
    {
        ResourceKey = resourceKey;
    }

    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return _ProvideLocalValue(serviceProvider) ?? _ProvideApplicationValue();
    }

    private object _ProvideLocalValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        var rootObjectProvider = (IRootObjectProvider)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IRootObjectProvider));
        if (rootObjectProvider == null) return null;
        var dictionary = rootObjectProvider.RootObject as IDictionary;
        if (dictionary == null) return null;
        return dictionary.Contains(ResourceKey) ? dictionary[ResourceKey] : null;
    }

    private object _ProvideApplicationValue()
    {
        var value = Application.Current.TryFindResource(ResourceKey);
        return value;
    }
}
```

The usage is similar to above, but the key is to use `Alias` as the markup extension where used, not `StaticResource`.  Somewhere in the application resource stack, define the resources...

```
<Application x:Class="WPF.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
             xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:WPF"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <system:String x:Key="Text">Display some text.</system:String>
        <system:String x:Key="Other">4</system:String>
        <wpf:Alias x:Key="Alias" ResourceKey="Text"/>
        <wpf:Alias x:Key="Second" ResourceKey="Other"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And wherever you're referencing the aliases...

```
<Window x:Class="WPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:wpf="clr-namespace:WPF"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="150" Width="300">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock Text="{wpf:Alias Alias}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{wpf:Alias Second}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

My solution required referencing strings, but it works for any object you want to alias.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to tuse the StaticResourceExtension, but in global resource dictionaries this does not work (strange compiler and runtime errors):

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StatusColor_OK" Color="#ff32a248" />
    <StaticResourceExtension
        x:Key="AliasKey"
        ResourceKey="StatusColor_Error" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

To overcome this problem, I created the following class:

```
/// <summary>
/// Defines an Alias for an existing resource. Very similar to 
/// <see cref="StaticResourceExtension"/>, but it works in
///  ResourceDictionaries
/// </summary>
public class Alias: System.Windows.Markup.MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        IRootObjectProvider rootObjectProvider = (IRootObjectProvider)
            serviceProvider.GetService(typeof (IRootObjectProvider));
        if (rootObjectProvider == null) return null;
        IDictionary dictionary =  rootObjectProvider.RootObject as IDictionary;
        if (dictionary == null) return null;
        return dictionary[ResourceKey];
    }


    public object ResourceKey { get; set; }
}
```

Usage:

```
<ResourceDictionary 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" >

    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="StatusColor_OK" Color="#ff32a248" />
    <Alias
        x:Key="AliasKey"
        ResourceKey="StatusColor_Error" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: If I try to use the alias somewhere...e.g. <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MyBrush" Color="{StaticResource MyOtherColor}" /> where MyOtherColor is an alias for a Color with key MyColor, then it complains and says "Invalid resource type: expected type is 'Color', actual type is 'Alias'".

Comment: To clarify, it does work if the alias is in a resource dictionary, and the alias is used outside that dictionary.  It cannot be used within the same dictionary however.

Comment: And spurious errors are raised and disappear as per my original comment. If I run the app successfully, then edit the XAML by adding whitespace, a compiler error appears. I build the project, it is still there. I build again, it disappears. It's very frustrating because your idea looked so promising!

Comment: I have a resource dictionary for colors and another for individual design element resources that alias the color resources. All is well until I try to use a design element resource in a form. Then I get compiler errors. Using this Alias class is a pain but it works.