# Is it possible to create a resource with multiple names in xaml?

Tags: xaml

In a `ResourceDictionary`, is there any way to specify an alias for a resource?  For example,

```
<Color x:Key="BorderColor">#FF000000</Color>
<Color x:Key="AlternateBorderColor">{StaticResource BorderColor}</Color>
```

I don't really want another resource called "AlternateBorderColor", I would just like to be able to refer to the original resource by another name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does *Redefine/alias a resource in WPF?* at [Redefine/alias a resource in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/634069/redefine-alias-a-resource-in-wpf) help you?

Comment: This would work, if I were using WPF and not Silverlight.  I don't think Silverlight has an equivalent class.

Thanks.